finding the right (older version) android sdk and commandline tools
I'm looking at the official website and it only shows me the latest downloads for android commandline tools, which do not work.
java --version says:
openjdk 17.0.13 2024-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.13+11-Debian-1deb11u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.13+11-Debian-1deb11u1, mixed mode, sharing)

when I go to run the freshly downloaded tools, jvm starts yelling at me with this error message:
 sdkmanager "platform-tools"                                                                                             [13:43:45]
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli
        java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/sdklib/tool/sdkmanager/SdkManagerCli has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0

Obviously I need an older version of andrid commandline tools, but where can I obtain them? Scrounging the android website has yielded no results. The archive page only lists android studio downloads, but I only need the commandline stuff.

Are you running sdkmanager "platform-tools" in the same shell that you ran java --version? Do you get this error for all sdkmanager options, such as sdkmanager --licenses?

If you are using Android Studio, then for a specific project, go to the Settings > Build, Execu... > Build Tools > Gradle and choose your JDK version for that project. Android Studio ignores the JAVA_HOME when there is specific version selected for the project.

Note: Your error says that, your current Java runtime supports version 55, which indicates that the project is using Java 11 (though your Java Home is Java 17). And it compiles by 61 means Java 17, which you already have. But probably it's not set in the gradle of the project explicitly.
I may be wrong, you didn't mention android studio, but as you added android tag, I suppose it might be the case you are facing. Have a good day.
